# Citing a published book that does not appear on MathSciNet

Tags: complex-geometry, citations, mathscinet

I want to cite some theorems in *Several complex variables. VII* by H. Grauert, Th. Peternell, and R. Remmert (eds.). It is a book published in 1994. However, I searched the publication lists of all of the three authors on MathSciNet, this book is not there.

Instead, certain chapters (but not all!) of the book do appear on MathSciNet authored independently, for example,

$\bullet$ Dethloff, G.; Grauert, H. *Seminormal complex spaces. Several complex variables, VII*, 183–220, Ency-clopaedia Math. Sci., 74, Springer, Berlin, 1994. (note a different author appear)

$\bullet$ Remmert, R. *Local theory of complex spaces. Several complex variables, VII*, 7–96, Encyclopaedia Math.Sci., 74, Springer, Berlin, 1994.

I'm wondering should I cite these chapters or the original book even if it does not appear on MathSciNet, or maybe both?

Comment: I don't understand the question: it's of course appropriate to cite things that don't appear in MathSciNet (which is broad but not exhaustive).

Comment: @SamHopkins I think I'm just surprised that this book is not on MathSciNet (I haven't encountered this situation before), but some chapters are there, which are not authored in three names, so I thought there are some reasons behind, maybe they want the chapters to be cited individually? That's why I ask this question.

Comment: If you send an email to MathSciNet with your own bibliography entry for this book, they might find time to add it to their collection.

Comment: In general if a book is really a collection of different articles by different authors, you should cite the particular article you are referencing. In BibTex I'm pretty sure the right citation type is "incollection."

Comment: In fact for the book you want, it's online here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-09873-8. And if you click any particular article in it, there's a little button at the top which says "Cite as" that tells you exactly how to cite it.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you for the instruction!

Comment: By the way you could check ZBmath too.

Comment: For what it's worth, sometimes (but very, very rarely) a book that definitely should be there is somehow overlooked. About 4.5 years ago I noticed that [**Set Theory. An Introduction to Large Cardinals**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0720422795) by Frank R. Drake (1974) was not in the MathSciNet database. (In fact, I believe I noticed this sometime in the early 2000s, but didn't do anything then.) I brought this to the attention of someone there (a frequent mathoverflow contributor, in fact), and while it's still not reviewed, it's at least indexed there.

Comment: If you click on the MR entry for either of the two chapters you list you will see the text "{For the collection containing this paper see MR1326617.}", and the MR number is actually a link that takes you to the entry for the book (the one listed in Francois's answer.

Answer (score 22):

The book actually *is* in MathSciNet: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=96k:32001

Comment: Thanks! I never tried to search by title. This book is not in the "Publications" of the authors, but in the "Related Publications" category, which I don't know before.

Comment: @AGlearner: the reason for that is because they are the *editors* of this book, which is a collection of articles.

Comment: @SamHopkins This makes a lot more sense! Thank you.

Comment: Same as above, but the search is by MR number: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1326617

Answer (score 9):

Here is a citation from Zentralblatt:

Grauert, H. (ed.); Peternell, Th. (ed.); Remmert, R. (ed.); Gamkrelidze, R. V. (ed.)
Several complex variables VII. Sheaf-theoretical methods in complex analysis. (English) Zbl 0793.00010
Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences. 74. Berlin: Springer-Verlag. 369 p. (1994).

This is not really "a book of Grauert and Peternell". This is a volume of Encyclopedia where Grauert and Peternel are participants. Mathscinet lists most of the
books of this encyclopedia under the name of the general editor (Gamkrelidze).